# Escape Maven properties on the command line

Tags: java, maven, versions-maven-plugin

I am trying to call `versions:set -DnewVersion=${revision}`, but *without* `${revision}` being replaced.

I tried to escape the `$` as `\$` or `$$`, but this did not work.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Where are you running the command? Windows command line, Linux command line, some kind of CI environment?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki From Jenkins, effectively on the Linux command line. I guess that this does not matter too much because Maven will probably behave the same on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Try this: `'${revision}'` - encapsulate `${revision}` inside single quotes - `'`. Try this: `echo '${revision}'` contrary to `echo ${revision}`

Comment: Check the docs for your Jenkins version because often the escape syntax is slightly different. For `Jenkinsfile` sometimes multiple \ are needed as per [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4).

Comment: Note that when invoking from the command line, you first need to avoid having the shell modifying the argument.  Put it in single quotes like `'-DnewVersion=${revision}'`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a trick to make Maven treat properties starting with `$` as strings instead of trying to substitute them:

```
./mvnw versions:set -Ddollar='$' -DnewVersion='${dollar}{revision}'
```

The `pom.xml` contains the desired result:

```
<version>${revision}</version>
```

A simpler but less elegant idea is to use `sed`:

```
./mvnw versions:set -DnewVersion='@revision@'
sed -i '' 's|@revision@|${revision}|' pom.xml
```