# How to escape variable names in maven inside a Jenkinsfile

Tags: java, shell, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

Hi guys im having a bit of a problem here. I have a pom.xml which has the  tag in the following form: `<version>1.0.0${revision}${sha1}${changelist}</version>`.

I'm trying to increment the minor version of my project inside a Jenkinsfile without loosing "${revision}${sha1}${changelist}".

I don't want the values from the variables instead i want my new Version to look like `<version>1.1.0${revision}${sha1}${changelist}</version>`inside my pom files.

I can't seem to figure out how to do the escaping right. My Jenkinsfile would look as follows:

`stage('Increment minor version') { when{ branch 'xxx' } steps { withMaven(globalMavenSettingsConfig: MAVEN_SETTINGS) { sh 'mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0${revision}${sha1}${changelist} versions:commit' }}`

I know this is not escaped right now. I tried multiple escaping attempts. Can anybody help me out here ?

I tried the solution of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59649766/escape-maven-properties-on-the-command-line) post too and got the following output: `<version>1.1.0{revision}{sha1}{changelist}</version>` as you can see the '$'-signs are missing.

I am expecting my pom files to have the version tag in the following form after incrementing the minor version: `<version>1.1.0${revision}${sha1}${changelist}</version>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries i finally made it work. This is how it works for me: `sh 'mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=\\\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0\"$\"\$\\{revision\\}\"$\"\$\\{sha1\\}\"$\"\$\\{changelist\\} versions:commit'`

Answer (score 0):

I already address your issue.

Here is my solution:

```bash
-DnewVersion=\\\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still need my 3 variables "revision,sha1,changelist" but not the value of those. With this code for example i would get the correct version number but it would add the value of the 3 variables behind the versionnumber instead of the variable names themselves. sh 'mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=\\\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0\\\${revision}\\\${sha1}\\\${changelist} versions:commit'